Why is たがる wrong here and ようだ is correct?
Reading a correction of a comment from a grammar video:

友達はJLPTを受けるからには、やはり合格したがっています。❌
合格したいようです。✔

I don't understand, the speaker is making conjecture about his friend's desires, why is たがる wrong?
Does it have to do with the use of からには? Or やはり? Is it about degree of certainty (as in, I bet you couldn't use そうだ because the speaker seems fairly certain)?
Also, if this is a matter of certainty, where does たがる fall in terms of certainty as opposed to ようだ or そうだ?

I am posting this as a word-for-word answer I received from a non-native speaker on this question, though I found it fairly convincing (though it may help with a bit more explanation as I still find it confusing, and this does seem somewhat technical):

Pretty sure it's the からには. The 合格したい is tightly connected with the からには, and changing it to したがる breaks that.
In my head, the way this sentence is structured is kinda of like:

「友達は『JLPTを受けるからには、やはり合格したい』ようです」

....so like everything inside the『』is spoken from the friend's "pov", sort of, if that makes sense.
I think it's that the subject of 受ける is the friend, so it kind of forces that part of the sentence to be from the friend's pov. That prevents したがる from being used because したがる is inherently from the speaker's perspective, making a conjecture about someone else's desires.
